# Wordpress count administrators -1

Tags: administrator

I have hide myself as a administrator (Supervisor), but when another administrator go to users, it counts him and me, so it says **administrators (2)** and I would like to change that to 1

Answer (score 1):

You need to run update query in database.

First you need to make that id=3 and the make the id=1 which you need to make it 1 and the again updated id=2 where id=3.

This is called swapping method.

Let me know if you need more help in this.

Comment: No, sorry I said it wrong!

We are with two admins so it says administartors (2) and I want to hide change the count in administrator (1). Not the ID, sorry! The ID was to explain I'm supervisor in Wordpress

Just a script to count admins total minus 1 (to hide my role)

Comment: Then ? what you want to do ?

Comment: count administartors minus one

Comment: We are with two admins so it says administartors (2) and I want to hide change the count in administrator (1). Not the ID, sorry! The ID was to explain I'm supervisor in Wordpress Just a script to count admins total minus 1 (to hide my role)

Comment: In Wordpress I have hide myself as administrator for another administrator, that works! But when he looks at users, it betrays that there are two administartors, so I would like to -1 the usercount of admins

Comment: Okay then you have to hide that administrator from css stye sheet.

Comment: okay !! Have a nice day,.. you can accept my answer if you want :-)